# How to read out complete mail preview on iPhone Mail app

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email

I lost access to my mail account, however there is one mail with essential info in my iPhone Mail app, yet the mail was never downloaded. In the preview section of the mail there is already a considerable amount of text of 5 lines. How can I completely read out all preview text, or maximize it?

Attempts so far:

- Looking for ways to access Raw source -> not available on iPhone mail (I think)
- Migrate mail to other live account in mail app and access it elsewhere with bigger screen-> does not work with not fully downloaded mails
- Resized Text in settings to smallest, this already increased the amount of text in the preview.
- Looking for " mirroring" methods that actually have rescale ( not resize) functionality so more text will be shown on a larger screen -> not found yet

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you can not recover access to your mail account you are doomed : the mail app save only the beginning of message while it is not read. Once you have read it once you can still see the contents as it is saved in mail app  internal database.

Comment: Hi, indeed. I am not a developer myself, any idea how I can access the mail app internal database?